# Можно ли получить содержимое iframe?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли получить содержимое iframe если `src` принадлежит другому сайту?

Comment: нет, нельзя. защита браузеров

Answer (score 1):

Нужно узнать кому принадлежит src и непосредственно от туда тянуть.